# SQL activity validates but does not update target dataextension

Tags: sql, automation, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have a sql statement that I am running as part of an automation which validates ok but does not update the target dataextension.
The activity pulls information in from one dataextension (table_a) and updates another (table_b) which has a primary key (ParticipantId).

This is the query:

```
select (select max(CAST(ParticipantId as INT))+1 as maxId 
    from table_b
    where 1=1) as ParticipantId 
,CAST("ROW ID" AS INT) as ROWID
  ,Status 
  ,Notes
  ,CONVERT(varchar(10),"Submission Date") as SubmissionDate from table_A
```

Has anyone came across this before? I dont know how to fix it.

the query should be looking into table_b at the start to see what the last ParticipantId is, then add one to it.

Thanks

Comment: where is your update statement?

Comment: Its Marketing Cloud. The Update happens as part of the activity